# GPS Driver for .Net/C# for Pulling GPS Data From Any NMEA-Capable GPS Unit

Tags: c#, .net, gps, serial-port, nmea

I have a mapping application and I want to be able to allow my users to connect any GPS unit which spits out NMEA data over a comm port or USB port.

Since the NMEA is a standard that the GPS units must adhere to, I'd assume a generic driver could be written to connect to the GPS units and begin accepting NMEA data. After a web search I was surprised not to find anyone who had done this for .NET in C#.

Am I missing something? Is there a level of complexity I am missing? Anyone have recommendations on how to make my application work with a wide array of GPS units?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's all coming across a serial connection.  You need the driver for the specific GPS chipset. It's usually some sort of usb to serial adapter.

Comment: Agreed with @TheGreatCO. Most devices provide either a direct COM port or a propietary-to-COM interface and the applications just use that COM Port, which is easily accessable in C# too. There are some opensource libs out there to parse the data, like http://sharpgps.codeplex.com/ or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/279647/NMEA-0183-Sentence-parser-builder (which I haven't tried myself).

Comment: In 2004 we had to use the GPS SDK/API from the specific GPS vendor, TeleType at the time, to grab the data from one of their GPS devices (can't remember the model) connected to a Windows CE pocket PC via bluetooth, and it worked. We were using .NET Compact Framework at the time. Just now visited www.teletype.com and I see the SDK is no longer free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really want a driver, you want a parser. The driver is what handles making it (almost always) a com port, and is device specific. The parser interprets the actual NMEA formatted data.  Look at this parser project

http://code.google.com/p/nmeasharp/wiki/NmeaSharpMain

The lack of results is probably more an issue of lack of difficulty than anything else, it is a very easy format to parse.

Of course you can also use the windows 7+ Sensor and Location API

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/article.php/c16973/Using-the-Windows-7-Sensor-and-Location-Platform-from-C.htm

If you have a choice I'd use the Location API, but that is just me, and it isn't as well supported for any GPS. You can use an adapter to convert any standard NMEA gps to one supported by windows 7 if you like

http://www.turboirc.com/gps7/

Though that may pose a problem if you have commercial uses planned (though it would not be that hard to write a replacement).

Comment: The SharpGPS project is exactly what I was looking for. The Windows 7 Location API is interesting, but in my organization, I need to support prior releases of Windows. Thanks for the help!